# HashSet for unique characters

Tags: c#, character, hashset

I have an array of `characters` which I will iterate over. Once I find a character which I have not found before, I do something.

This means I need to keep track of which characters I have already met. My first choice was the `HashSet`, but I am not sure if this is the right choice, since `hashing` a single character might take longer than just `comparing` two characters. I wonder if this is true.

1. Is HashSet the right choice for this, or are there better options which, for example use a very small hash, or none at all.

**Clarification dump**

The array is actually a two dimentional array, which I receive from a function written by a college. I need to locate the position of each character too. The position of which character of a certain type is not relevant, as long as the function is not called twice for a type of character.

What I need to know is all unique characters in the multidimentional array, and for each unique character the location of one of these.

Comment: What is a normal `Set`?

Comment: Hm I assumed there was a set in C#. give a few minutes to figure it out.

Comment: Seems like there is not. Let me rephrase my question.

Comment: I would recommend implementing what seems more logical to you. If you then have performance issues (or are just curious), use StopWatch and see for yourself which solution is faster, it's quite easy to write simple profiling.

Comment: Hashing a single character may well take longer than just comparing two characters, but it certainly won't take longer than comparing `n` characters. If your array has more than a couple of elements, a hashset will certainly be faster (though will use more memory).

Comment: Your question is "I wonder if hashing a character is faster or slower than comparing a character?"  You can answer this question yourself by **trying it**. Write the code both ways, get out a stopwatch, run the code a billion times one way and a billion times the other way and you will soon know which is faster. If you have two horses and you want to know which is faster, **race the horses**. Don't post "I wonder which of my two horses is faster?" on the internet and get random opinions from strangers who have never seen your horses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only concerned with *ASCII* then the best approach would be an array of size 128 and casting to an int.

```
 boolean[] array = new bolean[128];
 char c = 'a';
 array[(int) c] = true;
```

Any sort of larger encoding, definatly just use a map i would think.

Comment: What's your reasoning for suggesting the use of a map (`HashSet`, I assume) if the character range is larger? Saving memory? A `bool[]` large enough for the entire 16-bit Unicode set is only 64 KB. And you can do it in 8 KB if you use a `BitArray`.

Comment: A good HashSet implementation like the one in C# will probably not hit 64kb in a sparse implementation and you are comparing two linear approaches so overhead should be trivial with reasonable numbers of accesses. My resoning is its not clear who would be the better solution and when it doubt stick to the easy way, profile, and optimize only if neccessary.

Comment: No, a `HashSet` won't take up the full 64K. It will require 24 bytes per entry. So you'd need between 2700 and 2800 items before it occupied 64K. The `BitArray` looks attractive, though. If I had time I'd do a little performance testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a `HashSet` from an array like:

```
char[] array = new[] { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c' };
HashSet<char> hashSet = new HashSet<char>(array);
```

It would be a better approach than comparing and detecting duplicates by yourself.

Comment: But OP needs to "do something" if he finds a new character.

Comment: The array is actually a two dimentional array, which I receive from a function written by a college. I need to locate the position of each character too. The position of which character of a certain type is not relevant, as long as the function is not called twice for a type of character. This is why I cannot use what you proposed.

Comment: @AartStuurman, then may be `HashSet` is not what you need, you can use `Dictionary` with index being a key and `char` being a value, I am still not sure about your requirement.

Comment: What I need to know is all unique characters in the multidimentional array, and for each unique character the location of one of these.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about simple char I think you can go with something as simple as:

```
bool[] map = new bool[256];
```

And for element access:

```
map[(int)'a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're really worried about optimizing this, then you can use a lookup table for your characters:

```
var lookup = Enumerable.Repeat(true, 256).ToArray();
var otherCharacters = HashSet<char>();
```

then, you can use the lookup for the "small" characters, flipping it to `true`when found, and use the `otherCharacters` for the unicode stuff...

Something like this:

```
foreach (var c in myListOfChars)
{
    try
    {
        if (!lookup[(int)c]) { // do something }
        lookup[(int)c] = true;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        if (!otherCharacters.Contains(c)) { // do something }
        otherCharacters.Add(c);
    }
}
```

This will hit a slow bit for characters outside the range of the lookup table, which depending on your locale is either acceptable or not. For latin based character sets this should work fine!

Now... not all the world works in the ascii / latin-1 range... going through texts in arabic will require a different range.

**EDIT:** Um... I've just checked the output of `GetHashCode()` for numbers... well... it turns out that the hashcode for an `int` is the int itself... so optimizing with our lookup table is probably just stupid... I'm going to check the implementation of HashSet next...

Comment: This might be a good option, as performance is critical here.

Comment: Why limit your `lookup` array to 256 characters? It's not like the 128 KB required for a full table is a huge amount of memory. Also, there's no need for the `Contains` check in the `HashSet`. `Add` will not throw if you try to add an item that already exists.

Comment: @JimMischel, right, I aggree. Totally depends on what you're trying to do here. Still, I think the example is nice, because it shows a technique for optimizing the common case with a fallback for special cases...

Comment: ref your edit: `HashSet` still requires 24 bytes per entry, so there's a pretty big memory hit if the document contains a lot of unique characters. And there's the small overhead of resizing the thing as items are added. Another possibility, by the way, is to use a `BitArray` in place of the `bool[]`.